# Getting an error when using whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo in firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting an error when using whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo of firebase. What I'm trying to do is search on my database if it starts with the corresponding letters here's my code:

```
constructor(fireStore, rootStore) {
this._firestore = fireStore;
this._employeeInfo = this._firestore.collection('Employee');
}

getEmployeeInfo = async () => {
const employeeList = [];
const snapshot = await this._employeeInfo
    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("fullName", this.fullName)
    .get()

snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    employeeList.push(doc.data());
});

return employeeList;
};
```

Error is

```
"TypeError: _this2._employeeInfo.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo is not a function. (In '_this2._employeeInfo.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("fullName", _this2.fullName)', '_this2._employeeInfo.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo' is undefined)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Javascript, so you need to use it that way:

`this._employeeInfo.where("fullName", '>=', this.fullName)`

Here is the list of the available comparison operators with an example in different languages: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators

As specified in the documentation: ONLY "For iOS, Android, and Java, the comparison operator is explicitly named in the method."

Side note: if you are trying to simulate an autocomplete kind of style, you better use https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startat instead of doing string comparison.

Something like this should work:

```
this._employeeInfo.orderBy("fullName").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");
```

Comment: The '>=' doesn't give me the result. For example I have Richard, Mike, f1 in my list then I put "Mi" in keyword. The three still appears

Comment: It's because you are comparing strings between each other, the ">=" will work exactly the same way it works with string comparison in any language and will check the ascii table to compare results. The ">=" with string is not meant to be used as a SQL "LIKE".

Comment: I updated my answer to provide you with a potential solution to your problem. have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startat